# Does this porg "have a name" and am I purchasing IT?

Tags: star-wars, names, the-last-jedi

There's a lot of information about the porgs, which are bird-like creatures native to Ahch-To.   [Here's a fairly detailed summary](https://screenrant.com/star-wars-last-jedi-porgs-explained/) much of which is learned from marketing and merchandising material.

As we can see in the trailer, at least one porg goes for a ride on the Millennium Falcon with Chewbacca.

[image: A porg aboard the Falcon in the cockpit screaming with Chewbacca looking at it in the background]

Are the porgs all nameless animals or do they rise to the level of, for example pets or companions, garnering names or nicknames, etc?

## I.e. Does all the merchandise available now represent a particular porg or just any porg?

Comment: I realize some people will want to (temporarily) close this based on the future works policy -- but I'm asking about real products that are already available, and supposing there may be answers embedded in the merchandising already.

Comment: Hmm. Seems very Future work-y to me. Hard to answer now, trivially easy to answer after the film comes out...

Comment: @Valorum, whatever, fine.   But what of the multitude of *Star Wars* characters and species that aren't named in the films, but still have names from other materials?

Comment: I'm not voting to close it. You're not wrong that it may have already been disclosed and if that's what the question is asking, the it's firmly on-topic. I'm just pointing out that like the question about whether Episode 7 was going to be live-action, it's beyond trivial to answer it in hindsight

Comment: A glance at upcoming merchandise will reveal two things: The packages all just say "Porg", with no specific name — and there's more than one porg depicted in merchandise, such as in this two-pack of porgs to display with the Black Series action figures: https://www.bleedingcool.com/2017/10/30/black-series-porg-coming-next-year/

Comment: @recognizer:   Those are good points, worthy of an answer.

Comment: The real question is why does the Star Wars franchise keep adding these beacons of mockery to their films? Does it have a name? Yup, indeed it does: Jar Jar Binks. Am I buying it? Not for a second.

Comment: @KaiQing - It keeps adding them because kids like them. The reason you find it annoying is because you aren't their key demographic, hence they don't care less whether you like something or not.

Comment: @Valorum - Is that why all those kids dress up like vader and storm troopers on halloween? Nobody, not even the kids care for these idiotic characters in the end. I find them annoying because they mar the whole movie experience. Like the sound of bowling pins being knocked over any time object a crashes into object b. It's gratuitous, unnecessary, and doesn't help the story. Someone who doesn't care about the story said they will sell an extra $20m in products if we add a doofus in there. They're right on paper, but not fundamentally. That shouldnt be how movies are made.

Comment: @KaiQing - Every word out of your mouth proves that this isn't a film that's made for you. If you were 7-12, you'd think that the porgs were hilarious without trying to overthink their existence and you'd be pestering your parents to buy you one with ten days left until xmas

Comment: @Valorum - I would agree with you except I have kids who are into star wars and they never mention ewoks, jar jar, or whatever else they throw in for annoyance. I grew up with the originals. If they weren't catering to us then why put luke or han or anyone original in the new ones? Clearly we must have some impact on their production. And since I'm buying the tickets, yeah, I am probably a part of the demographic. No, porgs won't prevent me from doing so anyhow, so on paper they are a win. Fans will argue over them, but not write off the whole series because of them

Comment: @KaiQing  -I know at least one young viewer who, despite all attempts to educate them about commercialism and what a good film looks like, think that Jar Jar is actually quite funny and probably the best part of Phantom Menace.

Comment: @Valorum - I know a few too. I worked for a theater corporation when they came out and there were a few indeed. It seems like a heavy trade off to me. If I were in charge I wouldn't have sacrificed the seriousness of a pseudo-serious space adventure for a few extra bucks when I already own half the world. I'm not in charge though. Hey to be fair though... Jar Jar might have been the best part of phantom menace... shows what I think of the prequels though.

Comment: No idea why this is being downvoted. Porg haters :(

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To:   You **are** obviously the one who's most familiar with Ahch-To's native species.

Comment: @recognizer:   Did all the Ewok merchandise name the Ewoks?

Comment: @ThePopMachine Yes, starting with the original action figure line the packages say "Wicket", or "Paploo", or "Logray", or "Chief Chirpa", or whatever, with the exception of a few generic Ewoks in the action figure lines as "army builders". In plush toys and such, the vast majority of Ewok items are specifically of Wicket.

Comment: His name is Mr Porgleston. $19.95 at Target. You'll have one by Christmas.

Comment: I feel like, if you buy a porg, you can pretty much assume it's that one.

Answer (score 2):

None of the porgs in the film are given a name.*

I have not seen any named porg for sale.

So at this moment I believe they are all generic.

> * Chewbacca may call one of them dinner but I don't think that counts.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the movie, there may now be at least one family of porgs nesting in the Millennium Falcon (was a scene in the movie). None are ever named, although it might be that Chewbacca has taken a shining to one in particular.